# How I can print all table's content in different pages?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I want to print all content of a table but only shows the content at the first page, if the table occupies more than one page dont print all the content.

How I can print all content without losing pages bindings?

Option 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nonPrintable').hide();
  window.print();
  $('.nonPrintable').show();
});
```

Option 2 (Using printJS library):

```
printJS({
    printable: 'table',
    type: 'html',
    targetStyles: ['*'],
    maxWidth: 1500
});
```

Option 3 (This print all content without CSS):

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('table').innerHTML;
var printWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "");
printWindow.document.open();
printWindow.document.write('<html><body>');
printWindow.document.write(divElement);
printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
```

Comment: You can hide the current div when the user clicks on next, could you show the code so we can really help you.

Comment: What have you tried already? Also please do not provide screenshots of code. Wrap them in a code block. Read [why you shouldn't.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Question is really vague, but what I assume from your screenshots is that you want to an option to print out the table contents with a stylesheet.

You can use `document.write` and `print()` for this and add variables which links to your stylesheet. Tweaks might be done because I have no idea how your `DOM` looks like.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#print').click(function () {
        var pageTitle = 'Title of sheet here',
            stylesheet = 'path/to/style.css',
            win = window.open('', 'Print', 'width=990,height=590');
        win.document.write('<html><head><title>' + pageTitle + '</title>' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + stylesheet + '">' +
            '</head><body>' + $('.tableClass')[0].outerHTML + '</body></html>');
        win.document.close();
        win.print();
        win.close();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then simply e.g at the press of a button print the contents.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="print">Print here!</button>
```

This will also preserve page bindings.